# gsettings like tools for KDE

Tags: command-line, kde, configuration, alternative

We can change fonts in GNOME, XFCE, Unity sessions using terminal commands. But I haven't found any such thing for KDE. Is there anything that does the job of tools like `gsettings` or `dconf` for KDE?

To clear the question more, I know I can use System Settings GUI tool for changing settings. But It's boring to open it for simple task like this. Also It's cumbersome to use in a script.

I'm using KDE 5 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Strictly speaking: There are KDE Frameworks 5 (KF5), Plasma 5 and KDE Applications. There is no KDE 5. There is also old KDE4 tools - adding comment to the mook765 answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_System_Administration/Configuration_Files

> For scripts or modifying files from the command line, the command line app
>   kwriteconfig is very useful. kwriteconfig expects a configuration file name,
>   a group, a key, an optional type and a value, such as:
>
> ```
> kwriteconfig --file kickerrc \
>              --group General \
>              --key AutoHidePanel \
>              --type bool \
>                true
> ```

From https://manned.org/kwriteconfig/d47c2de0

> kwriteconfig is a command line tool to write values in KDE configuration
>   files.
>   Nonexisting files/groups/keys will be created.

This site gives also more detailed information about the syntax of the command.

Typing `kwriteconfig --help` in terminal will display something helpful.
`man kwriteconfig` does not work, a man-page does not exist in my system.

To read a Kconfig-entry you can use the command `kreadconfig`. `kreadconfig --help` displays useful information about the command. A manual does not exist in my system. https://manned.org/kreadconfig/40c5a73d gives more details.

These commands seem to be part of the packages `kde-cli-tools`,`kde-cli-tools-data`, these packages should be installed by default in Kubuntu.
You use KDE 5 on Ubuntu and these packages might not be installed, you should check that...

Comment: Both `kwriteconfig` and `kreadconfig` failed. I used this command with `kwriteconfig` `kwriteconfig --file kcmfonts --group General --key dontChangeAASettings --type bool true` but in `~/.config/kcmfonts` file the entry is still `false`!

Comment: @Anwar Try absolute path for the file, should work: `kwriteconfig --file ~/.config/kcmfonts --group General --key dontChangeAASettings --type bool true`

Comment: Yes, that works with absolute path. But this is kinda boring! Not anyway better than editing file manually!

Comment: @Anwar I agree, but that is what KDE is providing for use in scripts. Another boring thing is that the config-files a cluttered over several directories in `~`. I tried to find some better documentation, but seems really hard to find more useful information...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've upvoted it. KDE lacks here too much I think. But this is better than nothing at all. I was actually looking for changing fonts and it seems it is too complicated. I'll accept the answer if I don't get any better answer soon.

Comment: @ Anwar Thanks, if i get any further useful information I will add it to my answer.

Comment: There are two set of tools: For the old KDE4 and the new KF5. Ubuntu package : kde-runtime  - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kde-runtime . Is installing: kreadconfig & kwriteconfig. For the KF5 Ubuntu package is libkf5config-bin - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libkf5config-bin . It is installing kreadconfig5 & kwriteconfig5 . The KDE4 and the KF5 are having different paths for the configuration files. KDE 4 is using $HOME/.kde/share/config/ and the KF5 is using $HOME/.config/. Note: XDG Base Directory - https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html

Comment: @Anwar Based on the information of user26687 I found that the first command you used (`kwriteconfig --file kcmfonts --group General --key dontChangeAASettings --type bool true`) created the file `kcmfonts` in `~/kde/share/config/`.

Comment: @user26687 I have indeed both commands available in my system, didn't know that before. It does not seem to depend on `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, the variable is not set in my system which is pretty vanilla. But both commands work on the different directories as you mentioned. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @mook765 No, it changes the in `~/.config/kcmfonts`. I checked

Comment: @Anwar In your first comment you told that the value has not changed, I tried you command and had the same effect, the value has not changed (checking with Kate). With absolute path it has changed then. On my system the first command created the file `kcmfonts` in `~/kde/share/config/` which contained only the key `dontChangeAASettings`.